# Configure Remote Service broker

Tags: service, sql-server

I need help in configuring Service broker in sqlserver 2008.  My requirement is to transfer data from one sql web server to another web server. I have followed the all steps like created master key, message type, queue and certificate. but when i try to create end point like

CREATE ENDPOINT ServiceBrokerEndPoint
   STATE=STARTED
   AS TCP (LISTENER_PORT = 1433)
   FOR SERVICE_BROKER 
   (
     AUTHENTICATION = CERTIFICATE EndPointCertificateA,
     ENCRYPTION = SUPPORTED
   );

I get Error : Msg 1088, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Cannot find the object "EndPointCertificateA" because it does not exist or you do not have permissions.
 but i can see the sertificate under security tab of the database. how to solve this. I'm using windows xp with sql server 2008.

Answer (score 0):

The certificate must be created in master database. Once you fix that, the next error you're likely going to get is about port 1433 being used - unless you explicitly changed that, 1433 is the default port Sql Server uses for listening to client (not Service Broker) connections.

Answer (score 0):

check the access rights of user. the user (that are executing Creating Endpoint should have sysadmin access). It is permission issue.